# Get the following error while try to run Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I got the error while start the rails server by $bin/rails server. Please help !

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /mnt/c/Users/dande/Desktop/Rails/blog/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top >(required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try `gem install bundler && bundle install` and then running your rails server again.

Comment: Try going through these steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/34966790/5872935

Comment: @SebastiánPalma it works sir, thank you so much, thank you guys.